# Terraform plan reports a security group change for an instance that never goes away

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

One of my instances has the following configuration:

```
vpc_security_group_ids = [
    "${aws_security_group.dev-ec2.id}"]
```

Where the variable resolves to an sg ID value, let's call it `sg-abc123`

If I run the plan I get:

```
  ~ aws_instance.dev-master
      vpc_security_group_ids.#:         "0" => "1"
      vpc_security_group_ids.12345: "" => "sg-abc123"
```

And then if I apply I see:

```
aws_instance.dev-master: Modifying... (ID: i-abc123)
  vpc_security_group_ids.#:         "0" => "1"
  vpc_security_group_ids.12345: "" => "sg-abc123"
aws_instance.dev-master: Modifications complete after 2s (ID: i-abc123)
```

However if I run terraform `plan` again, the plan is unchanged - it still wants to add the SG even though it's added (and I can see it added in the EC2 web console).

If I inspect the state file I see a few things related to this SG in the `"aws_instance.dev-master"` key:

```
"depends_on": [
   "aws_security_group.dev-ec2"
],
```

But the state also lists:

```
"vpc_security_group_ids.#": "0"
```

If I manually edit the JSON (yes I know) to change this to "1" with the appropriate ID, no difference, `plan` still wants to do the change.

This isn't the worst problem to have but it does mean every time we run `plan` it takes longer to check what it will do excluding this action. Is this a known issue, should it be reported or is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Something is overriding your state file. Is there some service?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1993. No notice of when this is likely to be fixed though.